# React router v6 outlet doesn't seem to work

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <nav>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      <Link to="/child">Child</Link>
    </nav>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<ParentComponent />} />
      <Route path="child" element={<ChildComponent />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

function ParentComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>i am parent component</h1>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}
function ChildComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>i am child component</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I am visiting /child route I am expecting this output:
I am parent component
I am child component

instead of above I am just getting:
I am child component

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below code worked.Now if i access Home(/) route i get output as "i am parent component" and when i access Child(/child) route i get "i am parent component i am child component".
This is what i was expecting.

Earlier i was not nesting routes.Corrected my question accordingly.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <nav>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        <Link to="/child">Child</Link>
      </nav> 
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<ParentComponent />}>
        <Route path="child" element={<ChildComponent />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

function ParentComponent() {
  return <div>
  <h1>i am parent component</h1>
  <Outlet/>         
  </div>;
}
function ChildComponent() {
  return <div>
  <h1>i am child component</h1>
  </div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You probably never need to render** **a `<Router>` manually.** Instead, you should use one of the higher-level routers depending on your environment. You only ever need one router in a given app.

You should use `<BrowserRouter>`.

`<BrowserRouter>` is the **recommended** interface for running React Router in a **web browser.**

**So your code will be like this:**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<ParentComponent />}>
        <Route path="child" element={<ChildComponent />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

`<Router>` is the low-level interface that is shared by all router components (`<BrowserRouter>, <HashRouter>, <StaticRouter>, <NativeRouter>, <MemoryRouter>`). In terms of React,  is a context provider that supplies routing information to the rest of the app.

Comment: i did use BrowserRouter. In the imports i provided alias to BrowserRouter as Router.Forgot to correct that in my code sample so updating now.But with BrowserRouter also my code dont work.Anyways thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: it should work, have you imported `<Outlet>` too?. import { Outlet } from 'react-router';

Comment: Yup  @Haitham6373. Code is compiling properly and it has import mentioned by you

Comment: earlier i didnt put my question properly.I  have updated question and corresponding answer now.Thanks